# Related to android layout

Tags: android

This is my Apps login page . problem with that is when i run app on larger screens phones it is ok with that but  smaller screens  are not showing my button . what is wrong with my xml.  i have to use scrolls or some other solution exists. I did not use any absolute values so why i am having this problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:weightSum=".5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8sp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8sp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtpinid1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"


                  android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#222222"
                android:paddingBottom="5sp" 
                 android:paddingTop="3sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="15sp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtpinid2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                  android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#222222" 
                android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                 android:paddingTop="3sp"
                 >


            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
             android:layout_marginLeft="15sp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtpinid3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                  android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#222222" 
                android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                 android:paddingTop="3sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="15sp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtpinid4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#222222"
                android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                 android:paddingTop="3sp"  />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15sp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtpinid5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                  android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#222222"
                android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                 android:paddingTop="3sp"  />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8sp"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="12sp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"

            android:text="Login" 
            android:textColor="#fff"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18sp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
             android:weightSum="2" >

               <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
           >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNewUserID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="New User? SignUp" /></LinearLayout>


                   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
           >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtforgetID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="Forgot PIN?" /></LinearLayout></LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

the button is not appearing on smaller screens . any on can help me out of this. what can i do to resize automatically my layout to as screen of mobile. i have to use scrolls or some other solution exists. I did not use any absolute values so why i am having this problems.

Comment: design different layouts for different devices according to thier screen sizes and resolutions

Comment: Firstly, use android:layout_height="0dp" while you use weight property in Vertical LinearLayout

Comment: Remove android:weightSum=".5"

Comment: you are giving custom backgrounds for you views. Make sure you scale then accordingly and add different scaled backgrounds for different device dpi's

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, that will work in all device, Added ScrollView for scroling issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum=".5" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8sp"
                android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:gravity="bottom|center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8sp"
                android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="5" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtpinid1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:paddingTop="3sp"
                        android:textColor="#222222" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtpinid2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:paddingTop="3sp"
                        android:textColor="#222222" >
                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtpinid3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:paddingTop="3sp"
                        android:textColor="#222222" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtpinid4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:paddingTop="3sp"
                        android:textColor="#222222" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtpinid5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:paddingTop="3sp"
                        android:textColor="#222222" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8sp"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="12sp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonid"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:text="Login"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18sp"
                    android:weightSum="2" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtNewUserID"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="New User? SignUp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtforgetID"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Forgot PIN?" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Only code. No explanation? Plus using layout_height in wrong way while weight is there?

Comment: Why not make the `ScrollView` the root element? Redundant `LinearLayout` with an only child is redundant.

Comment: you can make ScrollView  as parent.

Answer (score 0):

you are using orentation verticle and weight property so u have give

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

insted

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

for ue child linear laouts only which are considered in verticle

hope it works for u..

Answer (score 0):

use scrollView for the parent layout 
Why are you using "sp" sp is more suitable for text, try using dp